# How to insert long datatype in Priority Queue Java

Tags: java, priority-queue

I want to store all `long` type integer to a priority queue, and I want to intialize the queue something like this

```java
PriorityQueue<long> pQueue = new PriorityQueue<>();
```

Is there an alternative available in java collections to achieve something like this?

Comment: nopes @tgdavies

Comment: What part of your question did that not answer?

Comment: @tgdavies While I am no thought reader, a guess would be that it’s not so much that that question seems to be about `int`, not `long` (not even explicit) but more that that question is asking about transferring numbers from an *array*, which isn’t the issue here at all. While you and I make the necessary abstractions easily, we should not expect the same from everyone here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java doesn't allow primitive types in generics. You must use wrapper class like below.

```
PriorityQueue<Long> pQueue = new PriorityQueue<>();
```